# Use Node.appendChild () but it doesn't show data

Tags: javascript, html, knex.js

I tried to create a table by extracting data from MySQL but the data didn't show. And there is no error show message ,so I don't know what I did wrong.

** I tried using Postman to see if I was using it correctly. The program can show the information page.

**This is HTML Code:**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped" id="employee_table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Employee_ID</th>
          <th scope="col">FirstName</th>
          <th scope="col">LastName</th>
          <th scope="col">Gender</th>
          <th scope="col">Dateofbirth</th>
          <th scope="col">BloodGroup</th>
          <th scope="col">Address</th>
          <th scope="col">Email</th>
          <th scope="col">ContactNo</th>
          <th scope="col">JoiningDate</th>
          <th scope="col">EmployeeType</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**This is JavaScript Code:**

```
let employeeList = document.querySelector("#employee_table > tbody");

let employee = [];


const loadEmployee = () => {
    userGet().then(data => {
        employee = data
        generateTableEmployee()
    })
}


const generateTableEmployee = () => {
    employeeList.innerHTML = "";
    employee.forEach(employees => {
        let tr = document.createElement("tr");

        let th = document.createElement("th");
        th.setAttribute("scope", "row");
        th.innerHTML = employees.Employee_ID;

        let tdEmployee_ID = document.createElement("td");
        tdEmployee_ID.innerHTML = employees.Employee_ID;

        let tdFName = document.createElement("td");
        tdFName.innerHTML = employees.FName;

        let tdLName = document.createElement("td");
        tdLName.innerHTML = employees.LName;

        let tdgender = document.createElement("td");
        tdgender.innerHTML = employees.gender;

        let tdDateofbirth = document.createElement("td");
        tdDateofbirth.innerHTML = employees.Dateofbirth;

        let tdBloodGroup = document.createElement("td");
        tdBloodGroup.innerHTML = employees.BloodGroup;

        let tdAddress = document.createElement("td");
        tdAddress.innerHTML = employees.Address;

        let tdEmail = document.createElement("td");
        tdEmail.innerHTML = employees.Email;

        let tdContactNo = document.createElement("td");
        tdContactNo.innerHTML = employees.ContactNo;

        let tdJoiningDate = document.createElement("td");
        tdJoiningDate.innerHTML = employees.JoiningDate;

        let tdEmployeeType = document.createElement("td");
        tdEmployeeType.innerHTML = employees.EmployeeType;

        tr.appendChild(th)
        tr.appendChild(tdEmployee_ID)
        tr.appendChild(tdFName)
        tr.appendChild(tdLName)
        tr.appendChild(tdgender)
        tr.appendChild(tdDateofbirth)
        tr.appendChild(tdBloodGroup)
        tr.appendChild(tdAddress)
        tr.appendChild(tdEmail)
        tr.appendChild(tdContactNo)
        tr.appendChild(tdJoiningDate)
        tr.appendChild(tdEmployeeType)

        employeeList.appendChild(tr);
    })
}
```

Or that I wrote the wrong code to another file.

Comment: Did you inspect the web page? Can you include the screenshot of your inspected webpage, console section

Comment: Inspected webpage, console section. It is a blank page.

Comment: Hi Merphy. Please post the source of your `userGet` function, and any relevant route definitions (probably the Knex code that fetches your employee list from the database).